# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') error in angular

Tags: angular

This is my model and im trying to loop to get some required data and i face the above error.

```
export class HubxDataModel{ 
    categoryId:number;
    categoryName:string;
    HubxDataItems:[HubxModel];
}
export class HubxModel{ 
    id: number;
    categoryId: number;
    itemTitle: string;
    itemUnit: string;
    isActive: boolean=true;
    itemValue: string;
    normalRange:string;
    itemColor : string;
    patientId: number;
    isDeleted: boolean;
}
```

Code that i tried to loop .Error comes at b.hubxdataitems line of code.From API i got the data for hubxdataitems array.

```
 let hubxdata: Array<any>=[];
    let hubxitem:Array<any>=[];
    this.hubxReportList.forEach((b)=>{
      hubxdata.push(b.categoryName)
      b.HubxDataItems.forEach((c)=>{  <---error comes here--->
        hubxitem.push(c.itemTitle,c.itemValue,c.itemUnit,c.normalRange)
      })

    })
```

how can i fix this issue.

Comment: `hubxReportList` or `HubxDataItems` is undefined. Define it. Aside from that, without more code, we'll be unable to help you further.

Comment: post the console.log of  this.hubxReportList

Comment: above problem is solved. can you help me with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73917323/i-want-a-dynamic-multiple-table-using-jspdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing i realised that from api you get camelcase `hubxDataItems`
whereas in foreach loop you try to loop a pascal case property: `b.HubxDataItems.forEach`

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach') this is the error i got i have double check and the error comes in this line too this.hubxReportList.forEach((b)

Comment: I updated the comment:
One thing i realised that from api you get camelcase "hubxDataItems" where as in foreach loop you try to loop a pascal case property: "b.HubxDataItems.forEach"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73917323/i-want-a-dynamic-multiple-table-using-jspdf   can you help me with this question actually im trying to solve this issue

Comment: It seems that you have fixed the issue. Can you please provide us the solution?

Comment: which one above question or the link i provided

Comment: The above question please.

Answer (score 1):

The answer has `data` in it. So this should be it :

```js
b.data[0].HubxDataItems.forEach(...)
```

Take the time to also push `b.data.categoryName` too.

Comment: not working when i tried b.data i get an error data does not exist

Comment: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'HubxDataModel' this is the error i got

Comment: You have to use the correct typing of your http call too.